# Updating image and input fild in into databse using php and mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I want to store an image and input fild in the database, not by inserting but by updating (by using UPDATE query).

when i want to push the button update, will show me blank page. Something I did wrong, but I do not know where is the mistake. Someone can help me to see where is the mistake?

edit-slide.php

```
<form action="update-barangg.php" class="form-horizontal" enctype=
    "multipart/form-data" id="baner_mic" method="post" name="baner_mic">
        <fieldset>
            <div class="control-group">
                <label class="control-label" for="focusedInput">Numar</label>
                <div class="controls">
                    <input class="input-xlarge focused" disabled name=
                    "kdbarang" type="disabled" value=
                    "<?php echo $data['id_brg']; ?>">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="control-group">
                <label class="control-label" for="focusedInput">firma</label>
                <div class="controls">
                    <input class="input-xlarge focused" name="firmaa" type=
                    "text" value="<?php echo $data['firma']; ?>">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="control-group">
                <label class="control-label" for="focusedInput">Nume</label>
                <div class="controls">
                    <input class="input-xlarge focused" name="numee" type=
                    "text" value="<?php echo $data['nume']; ?>">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="control-group">
                <label class="control-label" for=
                "focusedInput">kilograme</label>
                <div class="controls">
                    <input class="input-xlarge focused" name="kgg" type="text"
                    value="<?php echo $data['kg']; ?>">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="control-group">
                <label class="control-label" for="focusedInput">Pret
                mare</label>
                <div class="controls">
                    <input class="input-xlarge focused" name="prett" type=
                    "text" value="<?php echo $data['pret']; ?>"> <input class=
                    "input-xlarge focused" name="pret_micc" type="text" value=
                    "<?php echo $data['pret_mic']; ?>">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="control-group">
                <label class="control-label" for="focusedInput">Oferta
                %</label>
                <div class="controls">
                    <input class="input-xlarge focused" name="ofertaaa" type=
                    "text" value="<?php echo $data['ofertaa']; ?>">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="control-group">
                <label class="control-label" for="fileInput">Produs</label>
                <div class="controls">
                    <?php echo '<img src="../slide-mic/'.$data['imagine'].'">'; ?><input class="input-file uniform_on"
                    id="gbarang" name="gbarang" type="file" value="">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="control-group">
                <label class="control-label" for="fileInput">Promotia</label>
                <div class="controls">
                    <?php echo '<img src="../slide-mic/'.$data['promotie'].'">'; ?><br>

                    <input name="promotiee" type="radio" value="img0002.png">
                    DA<br>
                    <input name="promotiee" type="radio" value=""> NU
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-actions">
                <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Save
                changes</button> <button class="btn" type=
                "reset">Reset</button>
            </div>
        </fieldset>
    </form>
```

update-barangg.php

```
<?php
//panggil file config.php untuk menghubung ke server
include('../inc/config.php');

//tempat menyimpan file
$namafolder="../slide-mic/"; 

//tangkap data dari form
if (!empty($_FILES["gbarang"]["tmp_name"]))
{
    //tangkap data dari form
    $kdBrg = $_POST['kdbarang'];
    $promotied = $_POST['promotie'];
    $firmaa = $_POST['firma'];
    $numee = $_POST['nume'];
    $kgg = $_POST['kg'];
    $prett = $_POST['pret'];
    $pret_micc = $_POST['pret_mic'];
    $ofertaaa = $_POST['ofertaa'];
    $gambar_barang = $_FILES['gbarang']['type'];

    if($gambar_barang == "image/jpeg" || $gambar_barang == "image/jpg" || $gambar_barang == "image/gif" || $gambar_barang == "image/x-png")
    {           
        $slide-mic = $namafolder . basename($_FILES['gbarang']['name']);

        if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['gbarang']['tmp_name'], $slide-mic)) 
        {
            //simpan data ke database
            $query = mysql_query("UPDATE banner_mic SET promotie='$promotiee', firma='$firmaa', nume='$numee', kg='$kgg', pret='$prett', pret_mic='$pret_micc', ofertaa='$ofertaaa', imagine='$gambar_barang' where id_brg='$kdBrg'") or die(mysql_error());

            if ($query) 
            {
                header('location:slide-mic.phpmessage=update');
            }
        } 
        else 
        {
           echo "Gambar gagal dikirim";
        }
   } 
   else 
   {
        echo "Jenis gambar yang anda kirim salah. Harus .jpg .gif .png";
   }
} 
else {
    echo "Anda belum memilih gambar";
}

?>
```

Any help will be appreciated. 
Thank you.

Comment: Check the apache errorlog file, stop using `mysql` extensions and start using `mysqli` or `pdo` - please post any error messages found

Comment: kindly check your Redirection part `slide-mic.phpmessage=update` is it right?

Comment: [20-Aug-2016 13:49:44 Europe/Bucharest] PHP Deprecated:  mysql_connect(): The mysql extension is deprecated and will be removed in the future: use mysqli or PDO instead in /home/royalcan/public_html/inc/config.php on line 9
[20-Aug-2016 13:49:49 Europe/Bucharest] PHP Notice:  Use of undefined constant php - assumed 'php' in /home/royalcan/public_html/admin/update-barangg.php on line 1

Comment: whooo, uff I em so so ...., will change all my admin panel to mysqli format, Can you find the problem, just know where I did wrong ?